# How to make list view builder scrollable and set its height space as much as it can take?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, height, scrollable

I have a problem with ListView. I need to make it scrollable and set its size to max space it can take. Below listView I have a button that should be visible, but the ListView covers it.
I tried solutions from similar topics:

- put ListView into SingleChildScrollView
- make ListView Expanded

So the problem is:

- how to make this listView scrollable?
- how can I set its size to max as it can take (I mean it should be between 'List of participants' and Leave button)
- how can I attach this button to be always on the bottom of screen, no matter what size of screen I have?

I hope pictures help you to understand what I mean. I also add the code but it is formatted weird, so sorry about that.

Screenshoot from device with above problem:

[image]

How it looks on another device and how it should look:

[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter SDK'),
          centerTitle: true),
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: !isInitializedList
                ? Column(
                    children: [
                      TextField(
                        controller: usernameController,
                        readOnly: true),
                      const SizedBox(height: 12),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Conference name'),
                        controller: conferenceNameController),
                      const SizedBox(height: 12),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          // Step 5: Call joinConference()
                          await joinConference();
                        },
                        child: isJoining
                            ? const Text('Joining...')
                            : const Text('Join the conference')),
                      const Divider(thickness: 2),
                      const Text("Join the conference to see the list of participants.")
                    ],
                  )
                : Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                          'Conference name: ${conferenceNameController.text}',
                          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 16)),
                      const SizedBox(height: 16),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          const Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                  'List of participants:',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))),
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),

                        // Step 7: Display the list of participants
                          ListView.separated(
                            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return const SizedBox(height: 5);
                            },
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: participants.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              var participant = participants[index];
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                child: Row(children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                        height: 150,
                                        width: 150,
                                        child: VideoView.withMediaStream(
                                            participant: participant,
                                            mediaStream: participant.streams?.firstWhereOrNull((s) =>
                                                    s.type == MediaStreamType.camera),
                                            key: ValueKey('video_view_tile_${participant.id}'))),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                                "${participant.info?.name.toString()}"),
                                            Text(
                                                "status: ${participant.status?.name}")
                                          ]),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ]),
                              );
                            }),
                    ]),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.red),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // Step 6: Call leaveConference()
                      await leaveConference();
                    },
                    child: isJoining
                        ? const Text('Leaving...')
                        : const Text('Leave the conference'))
                ])
        )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sahre the whole code

Comment: The error would be in how it is added to its parent. Please show more code, especially in how it is added to the rest of the screen

Comment: Just added the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to make list view expand as much as available, you need to wrap it with `Expanded` widget, by that you tell to `column` give it space as much as you have, also you need to do this for inside `column` agin, like this:

```
Column(
   children: [
       Text('Conference name: ${conferenceNameController.text}',
       style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 16)),
       const SizedBox(height: 16),
       Expanded(// <--- add this
         child: Column(
               children: [
                        const Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text('List of participants:',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))),
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),

                        Expanded( // <--- add this
                          child: ListView.separated(
                              separatorBuilder:

               ...
)
```

[image]

Comment: Omg! It works for me. Thank you a lot. I didn't wrap the parent column in the expand widget before. Really appreaciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make listview scrollable with `shrinkwrap` parameter inside `Listview.builder()`